# How to force the duo Spring cloud sleuth - Spring MVC/Spring Rest to handle @SpanTag annotation set on controller's handler methods' parameters

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-rest, spring-cloud-sleuth

I got a Spring boot application set with Spring REST and Spring cloud sleuth. I am trying to set a custom tag based on the controller's methods' parameters with the `@SpanTag` annotation, but no luck

Here is an example controller :

```kotlin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
class ExampleController() {

    @PostMapping("/create")
    fun createToken(
            @SpanTag(key="username",expression = "username") 
            @RequestBody 
            authTokenRequest: Request){
//Some code here
    }
}
```

Got a zipkin running on the side for retrieving trace and span.

When I launch a request on `/api/auth/create`, I can see the Trace popping in the zipkin instance. If I has subspan, they show as well. The default tag are also visible on the root span (`http.path`, `mvc.controller.class`, etc.) but no tag named `username`.

So my question, is there a way to force Spring Cloud Sleuth (in this configuration) to acknowledge the `@SpanTag` annotation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/using.html), `@SpanTag` is *only used in combination* with a method, annotated `@NewSpan` or `@ContinueSpan`. (It would be nice to write it somewhere explicitly, but implicitly it makes no other sense;)

Please try:

```
@ContinueSpan(log = "createToken") //or a log of your choice
@PostMapping("/create")
fun createToken(@SpanTag ...
```

Comment: Will check as soon as possible, but I think you got it.

Comment: Work as a charm ! Thank you, kind stranger